# Exceptions in Haskell

Tags: exception, haskell

If I understood rightly, exceptions in Haskell basically intended to deal within IO monad. At least exception could be caught inside IO monad.

But sometimes even pure functions may throw an exception, e.g. `read "..." :: Int` (when reading string does not represent integer), operator `(!!)` (when we trying to get item out of range of the list), and so forth. And this is true behavior, I don't deny. However, I would not want to change signature of function just to get it chance to catch possible exception, because in this case I have to change signature all the functions by call stack before.

Is there some pattern to deal with exceptions more comfortable  in Haskell, out of IO monad? May be I should use `unsafePerformIO` in this case? How "safe" to use `unsafePerformIO` just for catching exceptions in pure functions?

Comment: I think those exceptions are the "you have a bug" kind, and as such should not be caught in the first place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In pure code, it's usually best to avoid exceptions from happening in the first place. That is, don't use `head` unless you're absolutely positive that the list isn't empty, and use `reads` and pattern matching instead of `read` to check for parse errors.

I think a good rule of thumb is that exceptions in pure code should only come from programming errors, i.e. calls to `error`, and these should be treated as bugs, not something an exception handler can deal with.

Note that I'm only talking about pure code here, exceptions in `IO` have their uses when dealing with the exceptional cases that sometimes happen when interfacing with the "real world". However, pure mechanisms like `Maybe` and `ErrorT` are easier to work with, so they are often preferred.

Comment: I disagree vehemently that exceptions in `IO` are fine and useful in Haskell.  You're always better off using `Maybe`, `ErrorT`, or a similar explicit method.  It's much simpler to reason about; exception-handling code always seems to go hand-in-hand with bugs.  It's more composable.  It's more maintainable.  They should be banned.

Comment: @JohnL: Hm, yes, that came out a bit wrong. I've revised my statement. I don't think they should be banned, though. Some things, like asynchroneous exceptions (painful as they can be), cannot be implemented with things like `ErrorT`. In practice, I usually end up having errors I intend to handle use `ErrorT`, and have things where the best I can do is clean up after myself use `bracket` and related `IO` exception functions.

Comment: Async exceptions certainly are a problem.  I should have qualified my comment that I only meant synchronous exceptions, because I don't see a better solution for async exceptions either.

Answer (score 5):

That's what monads are for! (Well, not just that, but exception handling is one use of monadic idioms)

You *do* change the signature of functions that can fail (because they change semantics, and you want to reflect as much of the semantics as possible in the type, as a rule of thumb).  But code that uses these functions does not have to  pattern match on every failable function; they can bind if they don't care:

```
head :: [a] -> Maybe a

eqHead :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Maybe [a]
eqHead xs = do
    h <- head xs
    return $ filter (== h) xs
```

So `eqHead` cannot be written "purely" (a syntactic choice whose alternatives I would like to see explored), but it also doesn't really have to know about the `Maybe`-ness of `head`, it only has to know that `head` can fail in *some* way.

It's not perfect, but the idea is that functions in Haskell do not have the same style as Java.  In typical Haskell design, an exception does not usually occur deep in the call chain.  Instead, the deep call chain is all pure, when we know that all arguments are fully defined and well-behaved, and validation occurs at the outermost layers. So an exception bubbling up from the deep is not really something that needs to be supported in practice.

Whether the difficulty of doing so causes the design patterns, or the design patterns cause the lack of features supporting this is a matter of debate.

Answer (score 3):

If you anticipate that a function such as `read` may cause an exception, then why not simply restructure your code to avoid the possibility of the exception occurring?

As a more direct answer to your question, there is [spoon](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/spoon).

Comment: Note that spoon does use `unsafePerformIO`. Shouldn't it have some `NOINLINE` sprinkled in there, too? Or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to go out on a limb and disagree strongly with the opinions of people who say that the solution is to "just avoid having bugs in the first place." I would structure your code around handling your errors within one of these monads.

One of the main strengths of pure functions (and FP) is the ability to reason about your code, along the lines of "if a function has the type `[a] -> a`, then for *all* lists of a type `a`, I'll get back a value of type `a`." Exceptions like these cut the legs out from under that.

A good reason for `head` being the way that it is, is that it's much simpler for beginners to learn list manipulations before `Maybe` and friends. But if you can understand a better way to do it, I'd avoid these risks.